# How to take users input to interact with API

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am trying to have a user input a city into the search bar and click search to have the information display for the users city. Currently I have the city hard coded but want to make it users choice.

CodePen link = https://codepen.io/joshdbushnell/pen/MNegpy

**HTML**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id = "containAll">
     <input id = "searchBar" placeholder = "Search for location"></input>
     <button id = "submit">Search</button>

    <div class = "weather-container">
      <img class = "icon">
      <p class = "weather"></p>
      <p class = "temp"></p>
    </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
var city = "Orlando"
var units = "&units=imperial"
var key = "&&apikey=c6c565397f8f456020e7b3fe71fa3ff5"


$.getJSON(
  url + city + units + key, 
  function(data){
    //console.log(data);

var icon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
var weather = data.weather[0].main;

    $(".icon").attr("src", icon);
    $(".weather").append(weather);
    $(".temp").append(temp).append('°');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onclick` function to your button by finding it by `id` that updates the variable `city` using the search bar value when the button is clicked:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
button.onclick = function()
{
    var city = getElementById("searchBar").value;
}
```

You can also add a listener if the `enter` key is used when in the search bar instead of a button by doing:

```
document.getElementById("searchBar").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) 
{
        if (event.key === "Enter") //Can also use event.which === 13 or event.keyCode === 13
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            var city = getElementById("searchBar").value;
        }
});
```

**Note:** This is only to update your variable of `city` and I did not use it to perform any other actions.  Also this is in pure JS without any frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a click event with the search button that gets the text from `#searchBar` and then does the lookup. **Note**: This answer uses jQuery.

```
 // Register click event 
$("#submit").on('click', function(event) {

    // clear output elements 
    $(".icon").empty()
    $(".weather").empty()
    $('.temp').empty()

    // Read the city from the textbox 
    var city = $("#searchBar").val();

    // Make api call. 
    $.getJSON(
        url + city + units + key,
        function(data) {
            //console.log(data);

            var icon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
            var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
            var weather = data.weather[0].main;

            $(".icon").attr("src", icon);
            $(".weather").append(weather);
            $(".temp").append(temp).append('°');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jquery, you can get whatever the user inputs in the search bar

```
var city = $("#searchBar").val()
```

As this code stands, it still wont do anything. You would need to wrap all your javascript inside a jquery.click, so when the user clicks on search, it will perform the actions.

```
$("#submit").click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
  var city = $("#searchBar").val();
  var units = "&units=imperial";
  var key = "&&apikey=c6c565397f8f456020e7b3fe71fa3ff5";

  $.getJSON(url + city + units + key, function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    var icon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
    var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
    var weather = data.weather[0].main;

    $(".icon").attr("src", icon);
    $(".weather").append(weather);
    $(".temp").append(temp).append('°');
  });
});
```